# Reset index for columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index       1          2
Species  AGRALB     AGRCRI
Count      2          3
```

but I dont want the first row to be there, I just want the dataframe to look like this:

```
Species  AGRALB     AGRCRI
Count      2          3
```

I know you can reset index with `df.reset_index()` but I only want to do it for the running index in row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if 'index' is a column or the name of your index but generically the following will work:

```
In [23]:
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.shift(-1).dropna()
df

Out[23]:
0 Species AGRALB AGRCRI
0   Count      2      3
```

Actually rather than shifting, I'd just take a slice:

```
In [31]:
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]
df

Out[31]:
0 Species AGRALB AGRCRI
1   Count      2      3
```

If you loaded this data from a csv, and the column names were on the 2nd line then you could just skip the first row `df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1)`

Comment: it was a csv, skiprows is the easiest solution but all of them work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

> Docstring: Return Index with requested level removed. If MultiIndex
>   has only 2 levels, the result will be of Index type not MultiIndex.
>
> Parameters
>   ---------- level : int/level name or list thereof
>
> Notes
>   ----- Does not check if result index is unique or not
>
> Returns
>   ------- index : Index or MultiIndex